# The best way to connect Next.js CSR React app, Django and PostgreSQL

Tags: reactjs, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, next.js

My question concerns programming a full-stack app.

On the frontend, I have a Next.js React app. I want to render it on the client-side and probably use SWR. On the backend, I have a Django app with a PostgreSQL database.

I have seen two approaches to make all of these work together.

The first one is to use Django to serve Next.js React app with django-webpack-loader and then to load React app within Django template.

The second one is to build two separate apps - frontend (Next.js) and backend (Django + PostgreSQL) and deploying them on two servers (e.g. Docker container).
I have read [this article](https://owais.lone.pw/blog/modern-frontends-with-django/) and it makes me lean towards the second option. However, it is a pretty old solution and maybe some things have changed since then.

What is the most optimal solution when it comes to connecting Next.js React Client-side rendered, Django and PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opinions may differ, but based on reading and personal experience, I consider using separate Next.js and Django apps to be preferable. This (1) helps with [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), (2) helps avoid making Django or Next.js do anything that their designers did not anticipate, and (3) is simple with Docker.

Here's an example project that uses docker-compose to manage services including a Next.js frontend, Django backend, and Postgres database: https://github.com/ModularHistory/modularhistory